# Program Slicing in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Anyone have any ideas or experience using [program-slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing) techniques for debugging OO projects in MS Visual Studio 2008? Tool suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, real useful program slicing tool often come within static analysis tools, for example, [CodeSurfer for C++](http://www.grammatech.com/products/codesurfer/overview.html) and [Clang of LLVM](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). If you're looking for C# tool and/or Visual Studio plugin, see [What static analysis tools are available for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635/what-static-analysis-tools-are-available-for-c).

However, they're not perfect implementation to the academic research results, please be aware of that.