# TeamCity static code analysis tools for .NET

Tags: .net, teamcity, code-analysis

I've been spending a lot of time in TeamCity lately and the duplicates finder and FxCop build runners have been fantastic. I've also got build targets in the projects for StyleCop so violation of these rules is being surfaced and I've integrated NDepend which produces some great metrics.

What other tools have people successfully integrated with TeamCity? There's plenty around that integrate into the IDE or run locally (as [discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635/what-static-analysis-tools-are-available-for-c)) such as ReSharper, but obviously to run on the build server it needs to be able to execute unattended and produce artifacts that can be surfaced in the build report. What options are out there that I might have missed so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are using [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) for code statistics especially LoC an Churn report also it generates nice looking statistics.
like [this](http://www.statsvn.org/demo/jodatime/churn.html).

Comment: I ended up with a great StatSVN integration with TeamCity: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/12/continuous-project-statistics-with.html

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody is still interested, I've integrated [ConQAT](http://conqat.in.tum.de/index.php/ConQAT) into TeamCity.

It has a great (and pretty fast) code clone detector for C# and java and generates an excellent and very visual distribution of code duplicates for the entire code-base.
It's actually a very powerful tool, not just useful for code duplicates.

It can generate interactive graphs such as this one:
[image: Sample code clone map]

I've also recently integrated [ReviewBoard](http://www.reviewboard.org/), a tool used for code reviewing (similar to Crucible), but in my case integrated through TC build configurations instead of the more common approach of using VCS hooks.