# Static analysis tool to check locking before access to variable

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, static-analysis

I know there are a quite a few static analysis tools for C# or .Net around. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635/what-static-analysis-tools-are-available-for-c) for a good list of available tools. I have used some of those in the past and they have a good way of detecting problems.

I am currently looking for a way to automatically enforce some locking rules we have in our teams. For example I would like to enforce the following rules:

"Every public method that uses member *foo* must acquire a lock on *bar*"
Or 
"Every call to *foobar* event must be outside lock to *bar*"

Writing custom FxCop rules, if [feasible](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/index.html), seems rather complex. Is there any simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading is hard.   Using locks is not the only way to make operations thread-safe.  A developer may use non-blocking synchronization with a loop and Interlocked.CompareExchange, or some other mechanism instead.   A rule can not determine if something is thread-safe.

If the purpose of rules is to ensure high quality code, I think the best way to go about this is to create a thread-safe version of your class which is simple to consume.  Put checks in place that the more-complex synchronization code is only modified under code review by developers that understand multithreading.

Comment: "Put checks in place that the more-complex synchronization code is only modified under code review by developers that understand multithreading" : Actually, that is exactly what we are trying to automate, because we currently do not have the process/flow/manpower to validate each modification. We are not trying to enforce correctness, just making sure obvious errors do not slip through.

Answer (score 1):

With [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) you could write a [code rule over a LINQ query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) that could look like:

```
warnif count > 0 from m in Methods where
 m.IsUsing ("YourNamespace.YourClass.foo") && ( 
   ! m.IsUsing ("YourNamespace.YourClass.bar") ||
   ! m.IsUsing ("System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object)".AllowNoMatch()) ||
   ! m.IsUsing ("System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(Object)".AllowNoMatch()) )
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

Basically it will matches methods that uses the field **foo**, without using the field **bar**, or without calling `Monitor Enter` or `Exit`. This is not exactly what you are asking for, since you want lock explicitely on bar, but this is simple and quite close.

Notes that you can also write...

```
m.AssignField("YourNamespace.YourClass.foo")
```

... to restrict a specific write/assign field usage on **foo**.

Comment: So NDepend works again the generated IL, and not the corresponding C# code? Hence the validation against Monitor class.

Comment: Indeed Vincent, while NDepend parses also C# for comment and C# Cyclomatic Complexity metrics: http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Inputs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions could be implementation of [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992). You define rules, run them at **compile time** (so can be also integrated in your CI environment if any) and get results.

For en example of using CodeContracts like a tool for code static analys see :

[Static Code Analysis and Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335064.aspx)

Comment: How would you write a contract that prohibits access to a certain filed unless a lock is taken?

Comment: @svick: locking doesn't necessary mean you use `lock` statement.  You can use other type `sync` objects in order to be able to check if object is signaled/locked/... whatever.

Comment: OK, but still, how do you write a code contract that checks every access to the field?

Comment: @svick: you can, for example: 1. Define a property and not field 2. You can on compilation inject IL that fires an event on every `__get` field access and check your rule.