# How to specify annotation/attribute for locking

Tags: c#, c++, .net, locking, code-analysis

In Visual C++, we have set of [annotation attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916381.aspx) - for example `_Guarded_by_` can be used to state that given variable is being protected by synchronization object given in this macro. Code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161624.aspx):

```
CRITICAL_SECTION gCS;
_Guarded_by_(gCS) int gData;
```

It simply means that integer variable is guarded by given Critical Section. The Code Analysis tool will detect and render a warning if variable is used without *guarding* the integer variable with this CS.

What is the equivalent in C# to state the same? I am not willing to use `lock` keyword, since I'm using [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) (lighter than `lock`). Hence I require some attribute/annotation against the variable(s) that I want to have synchronized access, backed by given Reader-Writer lock.

Comment: Maybe there is none yet. You can investigate if creating custom code analysis rules worth it ([click](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010/), [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9468601/1997232)).