# Extract template from multiple files ( pattern detection )

Tags: c#, code-generation

On a giving solution in C# (Visual Studio), I need to detect classes that follows some template and extract that template for later code generation.

In other words, I need to compare 2 classes (files) and extract a common template from them.
This template will be used for a later code-generation, when the programmer will have to write less code.

Is there any body who can give me an idea on how to do this ?

One more question, is there possible to get the syntactic/semantic tree made by Visual Studio ?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I user

- [NRefactory](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory) for compiling code and I obtained the AST.
- rewrite the code using custom labels (eq: for --> loop_start )
- flatten the tree obtaining a long label array (eq: class_start, method_start,...end, end )
  this was for 2 files
- I compared the 2 arrays using "greedy string tiling algorithm"
- and from here I already had the templates files.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I think you should look into diff algorithms to find common parts of 2 text files, e.g. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6943/A-Generic-Reusable-Diff-Algorithm-in-C-II).

For the second question I would suggest to take a look at [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is more a Plagiarism Detection like [Moss](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/). The code doesn't need to be exactly identical.

Comment: Roslyn is ended a good tool, but is only for VS 2012, with no support for VS 2010. Tnx

Comment: Ah, ok. Perhaps you can compile those files and then load assemblies for analysis via reflection, if you want to do it manually.
Or you can use some [tools (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635/what-static-analysis-tools-are-available-for-c).
And Roslyn has binaries available in [NuGet (link)](http://nuget.org/packages/Roslyn), so it might be used with free Express version of VS 2012