# Static Code Analysis from the Command Line on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, command-line, continuous-integration, static-code-analysis

I am coming from a native iOS / Android development background.
I am looking for some command line tools that would allow to perform static code analysis on our Xamarin project.

Are you aware of such tools? I have found [Gendarme](https://github.com/xamarin/Gendarme.Rules.Xamarin) but it seems that it hasn't been updated in a while so I am not sure how actual it is.

Also I have found [MonoDevelop.StyleCop](https://github.com/DarkCloud14/MonoDevelop.StyleCop) which seems to be an add on to Xamarin Studio (although we use Visual Studio for Mac - but it might just work) - but I can't figure our how you can run it from the command line.

What would be your approach into integrating static code analysis in your Xamarin Project Continuous Integration?

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm using macOS so I am interested in tools that run on macOS

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin is basically .NET written with C# or F# so you can use nearly all code analysis tools available for those languages. For a great list see: [What static analysis tools are available for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635/what-static-analysis-tools-are-available-for-c)

Comment: I am using developing on macOS though, so I need macOS compatible tools.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the project Xamarin.Forms using static analyzer PVS-Studio and wrote the article with the results of the check: "[Microsoft opened the source code of Xamarin.Forms. We couldn't miss a chance to check it with PVS-Studio](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0400/)". The check of Xamarin.Forms was performed for Windows (we don't have the version for macOS yet), but I still recommend you to write us to discuss this question. We have just started to make an adoption for macOS.